# Vue3 and Vue-Router cannot access the parameters with the $route object in production but can in dev

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm having some bad time with the build of a Vue3 app for production, literally 90% of my scripts are broken in production and that's related to my variables being undefined in production, I really don't know why this occurs. But for one of them I have a concrete example :

I access a parameter value in my route using `this.$route.params.myParameter` which works totally fine in dev mode, but in prod it's undefined and crash the whole thing

I can edit the question with code snipets but I don't think it's required

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself what was wrong with the whole stuff,

fitst I was using `this.myObj` in some component's template which = bad, remove the `this`, sadly Vue doesn't warn you about that.

Secondly I remade my inputs because using `v-model` with them does't worked in prod for a mysterious reason, so now it use `$event.target.value` on `v-on:input`

Comment: this isn't welcome in template because it's exhaustive but it's allowed and it's not Vue's duty to warn about it, a linter can do this if needed. Self-answers are welcome on SO but consider asking a question that can be answered next time, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This one couldn't be by anybody but you.

Comment: Ye sorry about that, I was going crazy because I coulcn't figure why it was working in dev but not in prod